# What class/service will give me business information for a latitude/longitude combination on Android?

Tags: android

What class/web service will give me business information for a latitude/longitude combination in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is anything native to Android that will get you that information.  Two online services I know of that provide this data are:

Google Places API -- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

ZoomInfo -- http://developer.zoominfo.com/page